# Refactoring Angular router into it's own module does does not work as intended

Tags: angular

I was able to reproduce the situation but first let me show you the code that works. I just put everything in one file for the sake of simplicity.

This code works as intented. When I click "First" I go to FirstComponent and when I click "Second" I got to SecondComponent even if I have refactored the SecondComponent into it's own module SecondModule, everything works.

```
import '../polyfills';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <nav>
            <a routerLink="/first">First</a>
            <a routerLink="/second">Second</a>
        </nav>    
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
export class AppComponent { }

@Component({
    template: `FirstComponent`
})
export class FirstComponent { }

@Component({
    template: `SecondComponent`
})
export class SecondComponent { }

@Component({
    template: `PageNotFoundComponent`
})
export class PageNotFoundComponent { }

const secondRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'second', component: SecondComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(secondRoutes)
    ],
    declarations: [
        SecondComponent,
    ]
})
export class SecondModule { }

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'first', component: FirstComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/first', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        SecondModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        FirstComponent,
        PageNotFoundComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

But now when I go a little further and refactor the main routing into it's own router module as adviced on the official pages, then it does not work anymore, because when I now click "Second", I go to NotFoundComponent instead of SecondComponent.

```
import '../polyfills';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <nav>
            <a routerLink="/first">First</a>
            <a routerLink="/second">Second</a>
        </nav>    
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
export class AppComponent { }

@Component({
    template: `FirstComponent`
})
export class FirstComponent { }

@Component({
    template: `SecondComponent`
})
export class SecondComponent { }

@Component({
    template: `PageNotFoundComponent`
})
export class PageNotFoundComponent { }

const secondRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'second', component: SecondComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(secondRoutes)
    ],
    declarations: [
        SecondComponent,
    ]
})
export class SecondModule { }

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'first', component: FirstComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/first', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        SecondModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        FirstComponent,
        PageNotFoundComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

I was following the official guide on Angular Routing which can be found here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

"I made it" to the end of milestone 3 until I ran into this problem and now I am stuck here.

EDIT:

I have uploaded the code into Angular 2 plunker.

Here is the code without the refactoring of the module: https://plnkr.co/edit/PlWvxDZGnA848OciyRQE?p=preview

Here is the code with the refactoring of the module: https://plnkr.co/edit/eYeiI9dRTZP6BDL5KeVQ?p=preview

EDIT 2: It works if I remove the wildcard:

```
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
```

But then where should I define this wildcard if it can't be at the bottom of the app router module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order in which the routes are declared matter.

With your current code, it looks like the list of all collected routes (after all modules have been imported) looks like this :

```
{ path: 'first', component: FirstComponent },
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/first', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
{ path: 'second', component: SecondComponent }
```

The path `'second'` can never be reached because it is "shadowed" by `'**'`.

To fix it, can you try importing `SecondModule` **before** declaring the routes of `AppModule`?

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        SecondModule,  // <!-- Look, I moved it BEFORE RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    ],
    // ....
})
export class AppModule { }
```